# Combinations over permutations and vice-versa?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Just wondering if there are ever probability questions/ situations where a set of combinations A is divided by a set of permutations S or vice-versa with uniformed probability measure? Or is it strictly when we consider events of permutations then the sample space must also be permutations, as with combinations?

Comment: Don't understand whoever down voted for a simple question of curiosity...

Comment: There is nothing necessarily bad about "a simple question of curiousity", but you should still do some research before asking, so that when you state the problem you want help with, you can add context that makes clear to Readers how well you digested the Question before asking.  One way to do this is by giving an example, perhaps one that addresses the problem only weakly or indirectly.  So asking without context often results in downvotes and closing the Question as "off-topic" for lack of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stay consistent throughout the problem.

Both top and bottom are combinations of both are permutations.

Comment: Thanks was just wondering of an exception

Comment: There is a good bit of sense to what you say in computing *uniform probabilities* over a finite set.  However I can imagine a situation in which that finite set is itself constructed by equivalence classes of combinations in such a way that counting does require dividing a number of combinations by an orbit size that is a number of permutations (i.e. a factorial).  One might wish to know the sophistication of the OP before attempting such a construction as Answer, of course.